# joomla invitex menu

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Just wondering, anyone can guest the problem.

I have joomla + invitex installed, so when i tried to create a menu for invitex in main menu, everthing looks fine.

But then the problem is, when i clicked on the invite menu, result in page not found. The url for invite menu looks funny, like this :

```
http://foxy.local/component/option,com_invitex/Itemid,35/view,invites/
```

Anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the foxy.local? If that looks wrong, it's a setting in your Joomla configuration.php file (the domain) or invitex settings.

Comment: Hi Zeno, Sorry, I mean not the foxy.local, its right. just the trailing part, instead of /component/option,com_invitex/Itemid,35/view,invites/  i think should be something like option=com_invitex&Itemid=35&view=invites

Comment: Try toggling the 3 "SEO Settings" settings in Global Config.

Comment: Yes, you are right, is because seo setting, but from sh404 modules. Just disable that, than it works.